# Не компилит прогу на c# в MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop

[image: Фото ошибки]

> Справочная сборка для инфраструктуры ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" не найдена. Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, установите SDK или пакет адресации для этой версии инфраструктуры, или измените целевую инфраструктуру приложения на версию, для которой установлен SDK или пакет адресации. Учтите, что сборки будут разрешены из глобального кэша сборок (GAC) и будут использоваться вместо справочных сборок. Поэтому они могут неправильно использовать выбранную инфраструктуру в качестве целевой.

Установил MonoDevelop, стояла .NET 4.7 и увидев эту ошибку установил 4.5 перезагрузил пк и не компилит и все.

Comment: Так в чем вопрос? Проект для какого фреймворка пишете? Если это для учебы, в чем проблема скачать бесплатную студию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно установить .NET 4.5 Dev Pack, а не просто сам .NET. Ссылки на инсталляторы dev pack для разных версий собраны в [официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers).

Для 4.7 есть [отдельный инсталлятор](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168).

Для 4.5 придется ставить [его как часть Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/hh852363).